# Why does using imported functon cause invalid hook error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a navigation bar as part of a dashboard page. The dashboard functions as expected until I try to include the navbar by importing and calling the function. I know the error comes when including the function call but am unsure what I am doing wrong.

NavBar Code:

```
imports ...

export const NavItems = () => (
 <div>
    <ListItem button>
        <ListItemIcon>
            <DashboardIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
    </ListItem>
    ...
 </div>
)
```

Dashboard Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List'
import {NavItems} from './NavBar'

export default function App() {
return (
  <div class="grid-container">
     ...
     <aside class="sidenav">
       <List>
         <NavItems />
       </List>
     </aside>
     ...
  </div>
 );
}
```

I expect the navigation bar to be included on the left panel of the site, but instead get the following error: "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:..."

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to make it a function component by setting an arrow function.

```
export const NavItems = () => (
  <div>
    <ListItem button>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <DashboardIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
    </ListItem>
    ...
  </div>
)
```

Or using function declaration:

```
export function NavItems() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <DashboardIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
      </ListItem>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: just to understand function declarations, can it work also like this? `export const navItems = function() { ... }`

Comment: What you have wrote is a function expression. You should have to split it into:
`const navItems = function () { ... }; export { navItems };`

Comment: @Dez Thanks for the quick response. Now it renders but the list doesn't appear. Updated question with a bit more explanation.

Comment: Because now, it is a function component so you have to render it like: `<List><NavItems /></List>`. For React good practises, PascalCase the name of NavItems in the declaration and in the import inside Dashboard code.

Comment: Thanks, I made that change but think my updated syntax somewhere is still a bit off, probably in the exporting/importing process?